Inconsistency between Program Id and anchor definitions
When deploying, the Program Id will be inconsistent with the anchor definition, but this will not happen when testing the anchor. I don't know how to deal with it. Do I need to change the Program Id defined in the anchor after deployment and deploy again?






If you call solana program deploy without providing the --program-id argument, the CLI will look for a keypair called token_claim-keypair.json and use that as the program id.
If you want to use your GTg... address, be sure to provide it when deploying it, ie:
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/token_claim.so /path/to/good/keypair.json


This is my first time writing Rust+Solana. Thank you for solving my two problems.
